# using .replace(char oldChar, char newChar) in java

Tags: java, replace

My array is setup to contain a string in every index. This string is a representation of an airline seating chart.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    airline[i] = (i+1) + " AB CD";
}
```

After the user has input a char value for the row and column they want to reserve, I should be replacing the seat with an 'X'. For example, they input: row: 1 column: A, at 1A, I should replace the A with an X so it cannot be checkout again by another user. I am using:

```
    airline[i].replaceAll('A', 'X');
```

After a print statement of the array, I notice nothing is changing.

Comment: strings are immutable , you'll get a new string from replaceAll()

Answer (score 4):

String is immutable. You need to reassign it to see the change, otherwise the change happens and you never see it.

```
 airline[i]= airline[i].replaceAll('A', 'X');
```

And you can check that in `replaceAll()` method. It returns a `new String`